# define a custom keyword in ios programmatically

Tags: iphone, keyword, custom-keyword

I want to create a custom keyword programmatically in iphone. For ex. NSLog prints the log in the console. There are my many frameworks that use their own logs (custom logs)like Aphlogs etc. I want to define my own keyword such as MYLogs such that when i use anywhere as `MYLogs(stackoverflow);` it should call a method "MYLogsCalled" with "stackoverflow" as parameter and i can perform my own actions in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a macro to do this quickly.

first create the method you want to call, so make a class called `MyLogs` and add a method

```
+ (void)myLogsCalled:(id)arg; //do whatever you want in the implementation
```

then define a macro

```
#define MyLogsCalled(arg) [MyLogs myLogsCalled:arg]
```

the other way is to define an extern function which handles the logs (this is what NSLog does), but using `#defines` makes it cleaner to do things like turn off logs in release builds [like DLog typically does](http://overbythere.co.uk/blog/2012/01/alternatives-nslog)

Comment: Can I invoke the above like mylog(test);

Comment: if you #define the same as my example, doing `MyLogsCalled(@"test");` would be the same as calling `[MyLogs myLogsCalled:@"test"];` so if you had a #define in the same format called mylog then yes